# Missing Favorites on Twitter

Tags: twitter

I had over 8000 favorites at the start of the year. I've been purging them recently and now I've got 5000. However, it's only showing the most recent favorites. The last tweets I noticed were from Jan 2014.

Is this a known issue, anything I can do?

Comment: It's probably a glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue. See the [Twitter Development Talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-development-talk/QwFMOTwuQOA).

As [Mark McBride](http://twitter.com/mccv) has written:

> You can use below link to report this issue,
>
> http://help.twitter.com/requests/new
>
> That way we can track volume and get a better handle on the issue.  It
>   seems fairly rare at this point, but that doesn't mean it's not a big
>   deal for those affected.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I did send a ticket to Twitter before posting here. Still no response.